# Munin RabbitMQ Plugin - always throws the timeout alert

Tags: rabbitmq, debian, munin

Every 5 minutes Munin sends me the alert: CRITICALs: Timeout: is 60.00 (outside range [:2]). The file that generates the error is rabbitmq-consumers

The graph is drawn well and the number of consumers it shows is correct. If I set an alarm with the number of consumers, the operation is correct.

[Plugin site](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/contrib/tree/master/plugins/rabbitmq) | Munin v2.0.33-1

munin-limits.log:

```
[PERL WARNING] Argument "consumers" isn't numeric in sprintf at 
/usr/share/perl5/Munin/Master/LimitsOld.pm line 408.
```

This warning also occurs with: messages_uncommitted, memory, messages, messages_unacknowledged

munin-update.log:

```
[WARNING] Service rabbitmq_consumers on debian-9-dev/127.0.0.1:4949 
returned no data for label _0_0

[ERROR] In RRD: Error updating /var/lib/munin/debian-9-dev/debian- 
9-dev-rabbitmq_consumers-name-g.rrd: /var/lib/munin/debian-9- 
dev/debian-9-dev-rabbitmq_consumers-name-g.rrd: Function 
update_pdp_prep, case DST_GAUGE - Cannot convert 'consumers' to 
float

[WARNING] Service rabbitmq_consumers on debian-9-dev/127.0.0.1:4949 
returned no data for label ___

[WARNING] Service rabbitmq_consumers on debian-9-dev/127.0.0.1:4949 
returned no data for label seconds
```

There are similar messages with the other plugin files

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the RabbitMQ version, I installed the last one available for Debian.

With version 3.6.6 everything works fine.